# Early loss stop and strategies to select best model

Tags: loss-functions, overfitting, tensorflow, optimal-stopping

Run config:

```
BERT_MODEL_HUB =
"https://tfhub.dev/google/bert_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/1"

BATCH_SIZE = 32 LEARNING_RATE = 2e-5 NUM_TRAIN_EPOCHS = 2.0
WARMUP_PROPORTION = 0.1 SAVE_CHECKPOINTS_STEPS = 500
```

Training set:

```
Class1    0.301805  
Class2    0.197109  
Class3    0.139705  
Class4    0.130531  
Class5    0.083358  
Class6    0.067785  
Class7    0.065793  
Class8    0.013913  

Class1    10000  
Class2     6531  
Class3     4629  
Class4     4325  
Class5     2762  
Class6     2246  
Class7     2180  
Class8      461
```

This is the plot of the loss on the training set itself:

[image: tensorboard loss plot]

Options I'm looking at now:

- Modifying training parameters above
- Introduce the *Validation* Loss / Other metrics at each step / n steps.
- Early stopping based on no loss decrease on training set
- Automatically selecting the best model from the checkpoints (saving best checkpoint as I go along training)
  Would benefit from some word of advice.

EDIT:
I have been using the 1000 checkpoint (loss 1.9151e-3) to predict on my validation set, but I get the same nonsensical "one class only" predictions.

Comment: Usually, I stop the training when the loss doesn't decrease during a certain window. min(smoothed_loss[-5:]) > min(smoothed_loss[-(window+5):-5]). Looking for better strategies also.